# Custom login screen image on Windows 10 after anniversary update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, desktop-customization, login-screen

Before the anniversary update, the lock screen and the login screen had two different backgrounds.  One had the Windows 10 logo, and the other could be set from settings.

Now, it just uses the same background for both, but gives me an option to turn it off, which will just use my accent color instead.  Any way to get a picture there again?

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/customization/58699-how-change-sign-login-screen-background-picture-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @wysiwyg They never answer this question in that thread, and quickly move on to other things

Comment: How you set both are clearly explained in that thread.

Comment: @Ramhound, please note that the methods that they use no longer work after the anniversary update...